# Runtime error 91: object variable or with block variable are not set

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to run the following snippet:

```
Sub Reliance()

    Dim htmS As Object

    Set htmS = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.rcom.co.in/Rcom/personal/prepaid/PlansandPacks.html", False
        .send
        htmS.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    htmS.getElementById("chCDMA").Click
    htmS.getElementsByName("circleStatecdma")(0).Options(1).Click
    htmS.getElementById("_getCheckedPack").getElementsByTagName("table")0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).Click

    Set Pages = htmS.getElementById("_getCheckedPack").getElementsByTagName("table")0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select

    Set newPages = htmS.getElementById("getCDMATopUpVal").getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = newPages(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText

End Sub
```

and got the following error:

```
runtime error 91: object variable or with block variable are not set
```

The error was not occurring while only `Pages` was put into the sheet's cell. This occurred by the `newPages` only. How can I fix the error?

**Extra Info**: `Pages` is accessing contents which require no button click/form submission. `newPages` needs those clicks to be made to access its members.

**UPDATE**- As suggested, the table tag was searched twice, now it is only once. Error is still coming.

Comment: Can you confirm the options you are looking to select on your page - not in terms of the HTML elements, just in terms of when you are browsing the page in your browser.

Comment: basically i am trying to fetch the header of circle name in the table after setting radio `CDMA` and `TOP UP VOUCHER` on with drop down set to "Andhra Pradesh" as option

Comment: Work from this URL instead http://www.rcom.co.in/rcom/revampRCOM/newChanges/getCDMATopUpVal.jsp?cdmaGsmVal=CDMA&subCdmaGsmVal=TopupCards&circle=AP - and let me know if you are still having troubles

Comment: yes, I can fetch data from here too. thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: I checked the page you're parsing, and the td with the element "getCDMATopUpVal" doesn't contain any div-element, so you won't get any results.

Update - as mentioned in comment, div and table will be created on click. Next guess is:

```
Set newPages = htmS.getElementById("getCDMATopUpVal").
getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")
```

so newPages are already table-elements.
Next line is

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = newPages(0).
getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0) ....
```

but newPages(0) by definition already is a table. Have you tried to adjust it to

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = newPages(0).
 getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0) ....
```

Comment: it will if those options are clicked on!

Comment: Ya, Sorry, I meant that only. There was a typo earlier. The bug is still the same!
Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Is it possible for you to start a new query for newPages when the user clicks the options / the table is created? Otherwise your function can't work cause the content of htmS doesn't contain the data you're looking for. You would have to create a second WinHttpRequest-object to get the changed html (which I guess isn't possible) or find a different approach.